# Laravel cart with paypal and stripe

Tags: laravel, paypal, payment-gateway, stripe-payments, shopping-cart

I'm creating e-commerce site in laravel 5.2. I will require a cart functionality [with & without login] with payment integration [stripe & paypal]. Is there any package or library that you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

For PayPal I would recommend [this](https://packagist.org/packages/angelleye/paypal-php-library).  Works great in Laravel and is quick and easy to make any API call you need.  Honestly, I'd also recommend just using PayPal Pro for your direct credit card processing, too.  That library handles both PayPal Express Checkout (PayPal wallet payments) and PayPal Pro (direct credit card payments).